# what to link with v8 under windows

Tags: c++, v8

I've been trying to get to get a basic v8 program working under visual studio 2010. I've been able to build v8.lib and v8.dll with no problems. I placed the .v8.dll in my debug folder, and added the v8.lib to VC lib folder.

I added v8.lib to my list of additional dependencies, but when I try and build anything using v8 code, I get a series of "error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol" errors such as "Error  13  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_EncodePointer@4    C:\KHMP\Game_Cpp\KHMPCpp\KHMPCpp\MSVCRTD.lib(atonexit.obj)"

I'm not sure what library I'm missing. V8 is definitely being linked as if I remove it from Additional Dependencies, the number of errors increases. I found something about needing to use ws2_32.lib, but including that in with my additional dependencies did not fix the problem.

Does anyone have any idea what libraries I might be missing/what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the kernel32.lib dependency.  Getting it from a file named MSVCRTD.lib is very fishy, that's the import library for the CRT.  Do make sure that whatever 'framework' you are using isn't trying to replace it.  And make very sure that you haven't been copying .lib files to try to solve another linker problem.  Like copying libcmtd.lib to msvcrtd.lib, that's guaranteed runtime trouble too.

Comment: that doesnt seem right, kernel32.lib is added automatically by VC2010 and i didnt remove it. This is my additional dependencies list right now (most of it was added by default by VC2010):
sfml-graphics-d.lib
sfml-system-d.lib
sfml-window-d.lib
v8.lib
kernel32.lib
user32.lib
gdi32.lib
winspool.lib
comdlg32.lib
advapi32.lib
shell32.lib
ole32.lib
oleaut32.lib
uuid.lib
odbc32.lib
odbccp32.lib

Comment: @user - have you been copying .lib files to try to solve linker problems?